# jquery Not working properly or I'm a dummie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to programming and now learning jquery.
I have to make easy Etch-A-Sketch app. I'm trying to make it in jsfiddle.net
Everything is fine? but when I'm entering width and height of my Grid it's doing wrong.
Example: I enter 10 (in width prompt) and 10 (in height prompt) but in result height is 20, width is 15.
Here is my jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
    var height = prompt("Enter your height (less than 64)");
    var width = prompt("Enter your width (less than 64)");
    if (height > 64){
        alert("You can't make height more than 64!");
    }
    if (width > 64){
        alert("You can't make width more than 64!");
    }
    for (i=0; i<height; i++){
        $('#container').append('<ul></ul>');
    }
    for (i=0; i<width; i++){
        $('ul').append('<li><li>');
    }
    $('li').hover(function(){
       $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
});
```

Here is html:

```
<body>
<quotes>Press the button to create your own Grid</quotes><br/>
<button>New Grid</button>
<div id = "container"></div>
</body>
```

And here is CSS:

```
quotes{
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
button{
margin-left: 130px;
margin-top: 4px;
}
ul{
margin: auto;
padding: auto;
}
 ul li{

list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
height: 20px;
width:30px;
border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

It's working but in a wrong way. Where is my mistake? Help me please to understand it.
Thanks for attention

Comment: Could you please add a link to your working jsfiddle

Comment: You likely  mean 
`for (var i=0; i<height; i++){
   var $ul =$('<ul></ul>');
   for (var j=0; j<width; j++){
        $('ul').append('<li><li>');
    }
    $('#container').append($ul);
   } `

Comment: sorry. I found a problem.

Comment: Did you link the jquery script?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working as expected because you're not closing the `<li>` in HTMLString:

```
$('ul').append('<li><li>');
```

So jQuery will create two `<li>` and append it to all existing `<ul>` on each iteration

it should be `$('ul').append('<li></li>');` or just `$('ul').append('<li>');` or `$('ul').append($('<li/>'));`

---

You can create the grid as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            var height = prompt("Enter your height (less than 64)");
            var width = prompt("Enter your width (less than 64)");
            if (height > 64) {
                alert("You can't make height more than 64!");
                return;
            }
            if (width > 64) {
                alert("You can't make width more than 64!");
                return;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < height; i++) { // iterate n number of times according to height
               // upon each iteration create one ul
                $("<ul/>").appendTo('#container')
               // create n number of li according to width and append them to the ul
                          .append(new Array(parseInt(width)+1).join("<li></li>"));
            }
            $('li').hover(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
quotes {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
button {
    margin-left: 130px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width:30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<quotes>Press the button to create your own Grid</quotes>
<br/>
<button>New Grid</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Works fine! But I'm not getting your code :) new Array(....)

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal just using the `join()` method of Array prototype to create HTMLString... For example, if we want to create a string of 2 `<li>` we create an array with 3 undefined elements and join them with String "<li></li>". so we get "<li></li><li></li>" ... I saw this somewhere in SO...

Comment: why +1 you're adding ??

Comment: Because if we join the array `[1,2,3,4]` with say a dot (`.`), we'll get string "1.2.3.4" - it has 3 dots, 1 less than length of array right..? So if I need 4 dots We should create an array of 4+1 elements...

Comment: So, you're appending the . instead of 1,2,3,4.... Got it now.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gut feeling I have about this code (I'll edit my post if/when the JSFiddle link is provided). I think you want a nested for loop, so that you're adding `li` elements inside the right `ul` tag:

```
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    // create the row
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');

    // add column elements
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        $ul.append('<li></li>');
    }

    // append the row to the container
    $('#container').append($ul);
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pacw62h9/) showing the code in action.

**Edit:**

If you want to clear the grid, all you have to do is remove the child elements in `#container`. Check out [the revised JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pacw62h9/1/).

```
var elements = $('#container ul');
elements.remove();
```

Comment: thanks) I found a problem) I just forgot to make ('<li></li') instead ('<li><li>').But now I found new one)) When I press button "New grid" it's creating properly. But if I will press it again all new width and height will be just added to current grid. But I need to make new grid every time I press the button.                                                                 Here is a link to JsFiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/myyfL2f3/

Comment: @ГарикБарабанщиков Even then you'll not get desired result. You may use T J code which I tested works very fine. To see with your code attempt to create the grid again after you create, you'll see the problem there.

Comment: Fixed this version of the code and included a working link. I think this version is better simply because it is less complex.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal It's working the same way as I want. But now I'm thinking about how to reset grid every time when button is pressed. T J code also have same problem. Every time it's just adding new grid to existing one.... And with my level of knowledge I can't use parseInt and so on))) I've just started jquery 3 days ago))

Comment: @ГарикБарабанщиков Then you should remove that ul before appending, or use html() method instead of append() ...

Comment: I updated my post to include the new requested behavior.